# DLL(thread?)safe error logging from VB?

Tags: vb.net

We used the methods found on MS' "Logging Errors to a Text File" page to build a simple error logging class. We used this in many of our VB.net files.

However, when we used this same code in DLL form, we found that messages from different consumers of the DLL were mixed together in the output.

Can anyone point me in the direction of "dllsafe" error logging code? One that separates the output into file-per-application or similar?

Comment: You're looking for log4net or NLog.

Comment: It is "simple error logging".  You make it more complicated by giving the client app a way to specify the log file name.